# React: cannot get properties from state

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app and am having difficulty drilling into state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid} from 'react-bootstrap'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';


class Pokemon extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pokemon: {},
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/150/')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          pokemon: json,
         })
      })
  }

  render () {
    const { pokemon } = this.state
    console.log(pokemon.species) // works
    return (
      <Grid>
        <p>{pokemon.species.name}</p>
        <Image src={this.props.image} responsive alt='member picture' />
     </Grid>
    )
  }

}

export default Pokemon;
```

Using React Developer Tools I can see all the data is in state.

I can perform

```
console.log(pokemon.species)
```

which return an object with two properties url & name. However when I try

```
console.log(pokemon.species.name)
```

it returns "TypeError: pokemon.species is undefined"

In state with just state = { pokemon: {} }, state looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have no pokemon.species before API responds. Try this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pokemon: {species:{}},
    }
  }
```

Comment: That works but I don't understand why. I added a picture of state as it appears without your suggestion. Wondering why I can't just drill into the pokemon object as I originally tried to do?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're trying to display your data before it loads.

Try this:

```
class Pokemon extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pokemon: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/150/')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          pokemon: json,
         })
      })
  }

  render () {
    const { pokemon } = this.state
    if (pokemon === null) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <Grid>
        <p>{pokemon.species.name}</p>
        <Image src={this.props.image} responsive alt='member picture' />
     </Grid>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you make the changes in the constructor?

Comment: No, missed that. With the constructor change it works. Also solves the problem of the pictures rendering before the text from the api call. So I have 2 good answers, not sure if I can mark them both as answer.